# Is there any way of using jenkins continuous deployment for AWS on demand instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I need some help or pointer about Jenkins continuous deployment to "on demand" instances of AWS. I was able to configure the jenkins slave for already exist instances easily. But, what to do if my EC2 instances are made on demand? Any pointer or solution might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the **[Amazon EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin)**?

> Allow Jenkins to start slaves on EC2 or Eucalyptus on demand, and kill them as they get unused

Comment: "With this plugin, if Jenkins notices that your build cluster is overloaded, it'll start instances using the EC2 API and automatically connect them as Jenkins slaves. When the load goes down, excessive EC2 instances will be terminated."- quoted from the plugin description. Does it mean that I will have to grant jenkins to create instances? But, it is already set to cloud watch to create instance on demand using image. let me know what you think.

Comment: I've never used the plugin, as I don't use EC2. Experiment and see what happens.